# show notification image and app icon in tray , while using FCM firebase plugin for notification

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

Right now I am using ionic 3 along with [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/)
for displaying notification alerts in tray (in foreground and background)
 I am not able to show app icon and hero image in tray notification.
Here's is the notification object that I am sending via [FCM google API](https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send)

```
{
  "notification":{
    "title":"Notification Title!",
    "body" : "Custom Dummy message comes here",
    "sound":"default",
    "vibrate" : true ,
    "image" : "https://image.png" ,
    "icon" : "icon" ,
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
  },
  "data" : {
                "id": 5462
            } ,
  "to":"/topics/all"
}
```

Comment: so what is this url - https://image.png? are you using exactly this one or a proper valid address? do you get notification but just missing the image?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko image.png is just some random png image I am using for testing. I am able to get complete notification with all data , title , body , etc , its just the image that is missing!

Comment: I was asking cause you need to make sure that url is valid.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko image url is valid only , no issues with that

Comment: ever solved?........